# How to Install Swagger-UI to Laravel 6 API for doumentation?

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-6

Installing Swagger for the First Time in laravel 6. https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger.

```
composer require "darkaonline/l5-swagger"
php artisan vendor:publish --provider "L5Swagger\L5SwaggerServiceProvider"
```

On generating command

```
php artisan l5-swagger:generate
```

Getting Error like:

```
php artisan l5-swagger:generate
Regenerating docs

   ErrorException  : Required @OA\Info() not found

  at D:\XMAPP\htdocs\minidmsapi\vendor\zircote\swagger-php\src\Logger.php:39
    35|         $this->log = function ($entry, $type) {
    36|             if ($entry instanceof Exception) {
    37|                 $entry = $entry->getMessage();
    38|             }
  > 39|             trigger_error($entry, $type);
    40|         };
    41|     }
    42| 
    43|     /**

  Exception trace:

  1   trigger_error("Required @OA\Info() not found")
      D:\XMAPP\htdocs\minidmsapi\vendor\zircote\swagger-php\src\Logger.php:39

  2   OpenApi\Logger::OpenApi\{closure}("Required @OA\Info() not found")
      D:\XMAPP\htdocs\minidmsapi\vendor\zircote\swagger-php\src\Logger.php:71

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

please Help me for generating swagger documentation

Comment: Please follow this link "http://promptsoftech.com/blog/how-to-use-swagger-tool-for-api-documentation/". easy way to generate the swagger documentation.

Comment: @RockersTechnology Thanks Its working fine in default Controllers. But facing issue in MdoularWise Development https://nwidart.com/laravel-modules/v6/introduction

Comment: Here is one good article and covered how to generate API documentation with an easy explanation so might be helpful to you. https://www.phparticles.com/laravel/how-to-use-darkaonline-l5-swagger-in-laravel/ Happy Coding 

Answer (score 1):

`Required @OA\Info()` is required to initialize your swagger documentation and then use proper annotation to parse. Annotations are only parsed inside `/**` DocBlocks. Here you go for initial annotations [swagger-php#usage](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php#usage)